# Копирование чекбоксов в следующую строку и неверная связь с ячейкой

Tags: vba

По нажатию кнопки "Следующий", активная строка копируется ниже с определенными изменениями. Всё хорошо, кроме того, что в свойствах чекбокса при копировании указывается неверная ячейка,где указана связь чекбокса с ячейкой.

То-есть нажимаю "Следующий", строка копируется,и чекбокс ячейки B6 должен обращаться к CQ6, C6 к CS6, D6 к CU6, E6 к CW6.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот сам код:

```
Sub Del_Row()
  Rows(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Delete
  Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 11).Activate
 
  n = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count
  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n).Delete
  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 1).Delete
  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 2).Delete
  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 3).Delete
End Sub
 
 Sub Copy_Row()
   Dim rw As Long
   rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Rows(rw).Copy
   Rows(rw + 1).Insert xlDown
   Rows(rw).Cells(1).Resize(2).DataSeries , xlChronological, xlMonth
   Range("K" & rw + 1 & ":AQ" & rw + 1).ClearContents
   n = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count
    
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 3).LinkedCell = "CQ" & rw + 1
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 2).LinkedCell = "CS" & rw + 1
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 1).LinkedCell = "CU" & rw + 1
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n).LinkedCell = "CW" & rw + 1
        

   Range("K" & rw + 1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Забудьте навечно про ActiveXXX !!! СтОит фокусу прыгнуть - и привет.. Получите ссылку на нужный лист, и используйте её. Или используйте блок With.